# C: Segmentation Fault: Runs on NetBeans (OS X), but not on Linux

Tags: c, linux, netbeans, linked-list, segmentation-fault

My program uses a pointer-based linked list. It opens a text file, add (a) /delete's (d) the content as specified to the linked list.

The program runs on Netbeans (MAC OS X). But when I run the program on Linux (RHEL 6.5), I get a segmentation fault.

I ran `gdb` and got the error posted below. Any help would be appreciated.

**CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct Node
{
    char name[42];
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* tail;
};

struct Node* Allocate_node()
{
    struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof (struct Node));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Memory Could Not Be Allocated");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    temp->prev = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
} /* Allocate_node */

void Free_node(struct Node* node)
{
    free(node);
} /* Free_node */

void Free_list(struct List* list)
{
    struct Node* curr = NULL;
    struct Node* following = NULL;

    curr = list->head;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        following = curr->next;

        Free_node(curr);
        curr = following;
    }

    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
} /* Free_list */

void Insert(struct List *list, char *string)
{
    struct Node* curr = list->head;
    struct Node* temp = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(string, curr->name) < 0)
        {
            break; /* string alphabetically precedes node */
        }
        else
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    temp = Allocate_node();
    strcpy(temp->name, string);

    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = list->tail = temp;
    }
    else if (curr == NULL)
    {
        temp->prev = list->tail; // Pointing Tail before New Element
        list->tail->next = temp; // Pointing old tail to new tail node
        list->tail = temp; // Assigning node to tail
    }
    else if (curr == list->head)
    {
        temp->next = list->head;
        list->head->prev = temp;
        list->head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = curr;
        temp->prev = curr->prev;
        curr->prev = temp;
        temp->prev->next = temp;
    }
} /* Insert */

void Delete(struct List *list, char *string)
{
    struct Node* curr = list->head;

    /* Find string */
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(string, curr->name) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (strcmp(string, curr->name) < 0)
        {
            printf("%s is not in the list\n", string);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    if (curr == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s is not in the list\n", string);
    }
    else
    {
        if (curr->prev == NULL && curr->next == NULL)
        {
            list->head = list->tail = NULL;
        }
        else if (curr->prev == NULL)
        {
            list->head = curr->next;
            list->head->prev = NULL;
        }
        else if (curr->next == NULL)
        {
            list->tail = curr->prev;
            list->tail->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            curr->prev->next = curr->next;
            curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
        }
        Free_node(curr);
    }
} /* Delete */

void printForward(struct List *list)
{
    struct List *temp = list;
    while (temp->head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", temp->head->name);
        temp->head = temp->head->next;
    }
}

void printReverse(struct List *list)
{
    struct List *temp = list;
    while (temp->head != NULL)
    {
        temp->head = temp->head->next;
    }
    while (temp->tail != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \n", temp->tail->name);
        temp->tail = temp->tail->prev;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *line = NULL, *name=NULL, *flag=NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read = 0;

    struct List *list; // GDB says *list is not initialized. Even after  initialization same fault.

    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
    /* start with empty list */

    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1)
    {
        name = strtok(line, " ");
        flag = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        if (strncmp(flag, "a", 1) == 0)
        {
            Insert(list, name);
        }
        else
        {
            Delete(list, name);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // Printing the List
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("/////////////////////\n");
    printf("/// Print Forward ///\n");
    printf("/////////////////////\n");
    printForward(list);

    // Printing the List
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("/////////////////////\n");
    printf("/// Print Reverse ///\n");
    printf("/////////////////////\n");
    printReverse(list);

    // Free Links
    Free_list(list);

}
```

**Text File**

```
Beverly a
Kathy a
Radell a
Gary a
Chuck a
David a
kari a
Tom a
Tanya a
Scott a
Beverly d
Brenda d
Kathy a
Gary a
WenChen a
Chuck a
Mike a
Emanuel a
Linda a
Bernie a
Hassan a
Brian a
Gary d
Kathy d
Gary a
Eunjin a
Kathy a
Brenda a
Jun a
Peanut a
Travis a
```

**GDB Error**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400c1a in main ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-         1.149.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: can you include initialization as you mentioned in comment?

Comment: No, I mean a part of source code where you initialize `*list` pointer @user3337714

Comment: @user3337714 I still don't see the initialisation of `list` in main. Please show the code with that fixed as that is definetely a problem.

Comment: I just posted the GDB error. It is now just simply giving the segmentation fault.

Comment: @user3337714 I think you are not understanding our request. You said "GDB says *list is not initialized. Even after  initialization same fault.". Please show us that code change. That is, the actual "after initialization" code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your part of code:

```
struct List *list; /* GDB says *list is not initialized.
                      Even after  initialization same fault.*/
```

`*list` pointer is not initialized (no memory allocated), initialize it like this:

```
list = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
```

If there is no memory allocation, it is [Undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Undefined behaviour can explain the problem "sometimes works/sometimes not". See link above to get more information about Undefined behavior

Comment: I got the following error `main.c:184:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'List'; did you mean 'list'?
    struct List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
                                      ^~~~
                                      list
main.c:184:18: note: 'list' declared here
    struct List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
                 ^`

Comment: `sizeof(*list)` or `sizeof(struct List)`

Comment: No problem. It was just a simple typo.